# App to share a calendar

Tags: calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Two phones — Two separate contact lists (me / wife) want to use same account for calendar](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18958/two-phones-two-separate-contact-lists-me-wife-want-to-use-same-account-fo)

Hey does Anyone know of an app that my wife and i could both download, and it would allow us to share and edit one calendar. So that as my schedule and hers changes we would know????

Comment: Related: [Two phones — Two separate contact lists (me / wife) want to use same account for calendar](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18958/two-phones-two-separate-contact-lists-me-wife-want-to-use-same-account-fo/18959)

Answer (score 6):

All you need is an Android with **Google Calendar** and two Google accounts for you and your wife (if you don't have those already). The Google Calendar supports sharing of calendars. You can create an calendar that you both can edit and that will show up on both of your phones.

Comment: That's what my wife and I do. We have our personal calendars plus _multiple_ shared calendars. We would never be able to get the kids to any of their activities on time without it.